# Dynamically import url in Django gives 'str' object is not callable

Tags: django

I'm trying to write some code to dynamically import "plugin-like" application in my django project. I'm using Django 1.10

I subclassed the `django.apps.AppConfig` class and used it to mark the plugins:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class AutomationAppConfig(AppConfig):
    def get_url(self):
        return self.name
```

then, in my project main urls.py I added this code after the main "static" urlpatterns initializazion:

```
...

from slae.util import AutomationAppConfig
from django.apps import apps

for module in iter(apps.get_app_configs()):
    if isinstance(module, AutomationAppConfig):
        url = module.get_url()
        urlpatterns.append(url(r'^%s/' % url, include('%s.urls' % module.name), name = module.name))
```

but it gives the following error when the server (re)loads

```
...
File "/cygdrive/d/workspaces/non-ide/slae/slae/urls.py", line 47, in <module>
urlpatterns.append(url(r'^%s/' % url, include('%s.urls' % module.name), name = module.name))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What I don't understand is that using this code instead it works fine:

```
from slae.util import AutomationAppConfig
from . import settings
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string
import inspect

for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    try:
        module = import_string(app)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        if inspect.isclass(module) and issubclass(module, AutomationAppConfig):
            urlpatterns.append(url(r'^%s/' % module.name, include('%s.urls' % module.name), name = module.name))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`url` is a function defined in `from django.conf.urls`. However the following line in your code overwrites this variable and stores a string there.

```
url = module.get_url()
```

change this variable to something else, eg:

```
url_route = module.get_url()
urlpatterns.append(url(r'^%s/' % url_route, include('%s.urls' % module.name), name = module.name))
```

Comment: thank you! I was sure it was trivial, I just couldn't see it... I feel stupid XD